# Why does my git completion of branches not work?

Tags: git, bash, completion

I am trying to implement my own version of the git-extras' `git delete-branch`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Assert there is at least one branch provided
test -z $1 && echo "branch required." 1>&2 && exit 1

for branch in "$@"
do
  remote=$(git config branch.$branch.remote)
  test -z $remote && remote="origin"
  ref=$(git config branch.$branch.merge)
  test -z $ref && ref="refs/heads/$branch"

  git branch -D $branch
  git branch -d -r $remote/$branch
  git push $remote :$ref
done
```

As taken from here: https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-delete-branch

Of course that would not make that much sense if we would not have the completion for branches with it, which is represented by this code:

```sh
_git_delete_branch(){
    __gitcomp "$(__git_heads)"
}
```

As taken from here: https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master#L_51/etc/bash_completion.sh

After installing the git-extras to try that code out it worked pretty good, but as I stated in the question, I want to implement my own way, because I want to check if the branches are integrated in the `stable` before deleting them.

Since I do not want to put my script in the `bash_completion.d` folder, I created this script:

#!/bin/bash

```
_delete_git_branch(){
  __gitcomp "$(__git_heads)"
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _delete_git_branch delete_git_branch
```

Which is included via `source` in my `~/.bash_profile`.
If I type `delete_git_branch [TAB][TAB]` in my terminal now, I get my branches.
But if I try to limit the results of the completion by typing `delete_git_branch 1[TAB][TAB]` I get the exact same results as for the first one.

I think I am missing some parameter passing here, but I am not sure.

Can you think of anything I have missed?
I can not see the difference between my script and the one that git-extras uses, except for the use of the `bash_completion.d` folder instead of the `complete` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since I asked multiple questions (sorry), I will split this answer:

### Non-working partial completion

Okay, I seem to have find the answer why this is not work as expected.

The [Git completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L2732) is wrapping the `git` command.
This wrap calls `__git_func_wrap` which has the following line of code:

```sh
_get_comp_words_by_ref -n =: cur words cword prev
```

This line assigns the parameters to their named counterparts.
As far as I understood the `$cur` variable is the one used inside the whole git completion script to determine the string to complete.
If that assigning function is not called, we would have an empty `$cur` all the time and though no limited completion.

So this is how my completion file does look like now:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

_delete_git_branch(){
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n =: cur words cword prev
  __gitcomp "$(__git_heads)"
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _delete_git_branch delete_git_branch
```

This is dirty of course, but calling for example `_git` resulted in duplicated calls which led to the same problem as before (I do not know why, by the way).

I know this is DIRTY as hell, but I am happy to take your feedback on my solution.

### Differences in completion implementation

About the part why the completion of git-extras does work out of the box and without the use of `complete`:
It does of course not work totally without `complete`. But since it is just a `git` sub-command it is also wrapped by the git completion.

It seems that if you are running git completion for a sub-command, it tries to guess the function name for it https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L2606.

And then it executes the function. Simple as that :)

### Moral

Oh yeah, I forgot about the moral:
If you really, really, really need to create a command with git completion outside of the git sub-commands, you can do this (or better with a combination of this and the comments that my come to this answer). But in any other case, you should stick as close to the git sub-command implementation as possible. Just to spare such hassle ;)

Answer (score 0):

The completion of `git branch` should work better with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021): the command line completion (in `contrib/`) completed "[`git branch -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/006c5f79be55c029d6f68ea0d5a33cb41d1b5e80/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L97)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup> with branch names, but "[`git branch -D`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/006c5f79be55c029d6f68ea0d5a33cb41d1b5e80/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L103)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--D))</sup> offered tagnames in addition, which has been corrected.
"[`git branch -M`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/006c5f79be55c029d6f68ea0d5a33cb41d1b5e80/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L129)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--M))</sup> had the same problem.

See [commit 27dc071](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27dc071b9a11e953ea7d73bfdf6103940d039215), [commit bca362c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bca362c1f94164f23e1c9b5cf833804d46315cbe) (03 Feb 2021), and [commit a534cf4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a534cf4f4d5ac58b91112fc12478d8a32e348152) (02 Feb 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 006c5f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/006c5f79be55c029d6f68ea0d5a33cb41d1b5e80), 12 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bca362c1f94164f23e1c9b5cf833804d46315cbe): handle other variants of "branch -m"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We didn't special-case "`branch -M`" (with a capital M) the same as "`branch -m`", nor any of the "`--copy`" variants.
> As a result these offered any ref as the next candidate, and not just branch names.
>
> Note that I rewrapped case-arm line since it's now quite long, and likewise the one below it for consistency.
> I also re-ordered the existing "`-D`" to make it more obvious how the cases group together.

And:

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a534cf4f4d5ac58b91112fc12478d8a32e348152): treat "`branch -D`" the same way as "`branch -d`"
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Paul Jolly</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The former offers not just branches but tags as completion candidates.
>
> Mimic how "`branch -d`" limits its suggestion to branch names.